# How to show a model after form post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a situation where I get the value only after the form post. I need to show these values on an HTML model. But when the form post happens the page is refreshed and model vanishes.

Is there any way to show the html model after the form post?

```html
<div id="uploadCSV" class="tab-pane fade">
        <form class="form form-vertical" action="{% url 'add_stores_bulk' %}" method="post"
              enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frm">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset>
                    <!-- Button (Double) -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="button1id"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <button id="button1id" name="button1id" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" id="uploadStoreCSVBtn" name="uploadStoreCSVBtn"
                                    class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addBulkStoreMsgModal">
                                Upload
                            </button>
                            <div id="addBulkStoreMsgModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">

                                    <!-- Modal content-->
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title text-danger">Alert!</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body" id="addBulkStoreMsgModalBody">
                                            {{ response }}
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: You should use AJAX.

Comment: on page load, check if the value exists, if exists, `$('#addBulkStoreMsgModal').modal('show')`

Comment: but once the page load happens the model vanishes. can you write the code for it?